# How to create Client-Server ( not in local )

Tags: python, client-server

So, I'm confused, I'm used to create a client-server in local but not ( client in one computer and server in an other). Can you explain me if I have the client in one computer and server in an ohter computer what what should I do ?

I mean, in the server I have the database to store the data of the web pages ( of the client ).

When the client is going in a webpage he has to fill a form and then to click on "ok" to going to the next page, but when he click on "ok" , the next page must contain the server IP in the URL , no ?

I tried to use REMOTE_ADDR ( but that's wrong ) I need to retrieve the server IP .... but what is the variable to get that ?

Comment: No it doesn't have to include server IP. There's this thing, called DNS that resolves "names" to IP addresses. How did you get to that page in the first place?

Comment: well, I try to make a thin client, I execute my script in command line with parameters like this : ./scriptpy serverIP param2 param3 param4, it opens the webbrowser with param2 to param4 in the webpage and I have to fill some data and click on "OK" button to going to the next page, but now , when I click on "OK" button I have localhost ... in the URL ( which shows that is local ), but actually, the webpages are stored in the server computer ( no ?)

Comment: that means when the client click on the "ok" he has to have the URL of the server or no ? - I'm confused because I'm used to create client and server in the same computer :(

Comment: Looks like you are doing something really weird. I would suggest reimplementing what you already have using some well-established library or tool, e.g. Django, Flask, Pyramid, Tornado or whatever else.

Comment: So the question is simple, if the client want to access to the webpage ( webpage is stored in the server - server computer - ), well, know if the client ( me, or to or anyone) fill some data and click on "ok" button to access in the next webpage, he don't have to have localhost because he's the client .... you know ....

Comment: Yes I know. And you must understand that your approach is flawed. The problem lies in how you render the page on server, so please correct it. Also, I believe there's the concept of *relative* url, which basically means that `/something` in html is automatically translated by browser to http://server_name_or_ip/something when navigating link/posting form, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest thing for you, given the problems you've had with previous questions, would be to use an existing web framework. [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com) is probably the easiest to get up and running.

Comment: This is rather comment, isn't it?

Comment: @J0HN No, not really. The OP has been struggling for days with a very simple thing. He needs to rethink his approach completely and use the tools that already exist to solve his problem.

Comment: But anyway, it doesn't answer *this particular question*. IMHO, it's a comment, and a question should be just closed than.

Comment: @DanielRoseman : The thing it's, I can install other module, just use standard module of python 2.7 :(